# Auto-create/name new Google spreadsheets for names in column list

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How do I auto-create multiple spreadsheets from a list of names contained in separate rows in a 'master/template' spreadsheet (up to 50 names, if possible)?

I think I am looking for a script/code/function/app that creates a new spreadsheet for each name listed in several rows in an existing spreadsheet. I found a function(?) that creates a new spreadsheet, but it doesn't do exactly what I want: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#create(String,Integer,Integer)

Comment: The question is too broad. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Also include a brief description of your search and research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: Thanks for your response. How about starting with #1 in my initial question:
I would like to auto-create multiple spreadsheets from a list of names in separate rows in a 'master/template' spreadsheet (up to 50 names, if possible). Thanks.

Comment: It's fine to start with #1.Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Which aspect/s of the question should be edited to make it appropriate for this instance? Thanks

Comment: See [ask] and [How do I write a great question?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3857/88163)

Comment: Not sure if it is the title, body, or tags that make the question ineffective. So, I will start with the body.
How do I auto-create multiple spreadsheets from a list of names in separate rows in a 'master/template' spreadsheet (up to 50 names, if possible)?

Comment: Please click [edit], make the changes on the question that you mentioned then click on "Save edits".

Comment: The revision 3 makes the question specific which is good but it doesn't include enough detail to identify an adequate answer as it's not mentioned what you know about the Google Sheets related features. Have you already tried to make a macro or script? Have you already looked at the add-ons store to look if there are an add-on that does what are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance in helping me craft an impeccable question. In the meantime, do you know how to auto-create multiple spreadsheets from a list of names contained in separate rows in a 'master/template' spreadsheet (up to 50 names, if possible)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean/expect by auto-create that is why I made several questions on my previous comment.

Comment: I apologize for not understanding the terminology. I think I am looking for a script/code/function/app that creates a new spreadsheet for each name listed in several rows in an existing spreadsheet. I found a function(?) that creates a new spreadsheet, but it doesn't do exactly what I want: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#create(String,Integer,Integer)

Answer (score 1):

## 1:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [{name: "Add Student one by one", functionName: "addSheet"},
  ];
  ss.addMenu("master/instructor", menuEntries);
}

function addSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var rData = sh.getRange(row, 1, 1, 3).getValues();

  if (row == 1) {
    ss.toast("This is the header");    
    return
  }

  if(rData[0][0] != null || rData[0][1] != null || rData[0][2] != null) {
    try {      
      ss.insertSheet(rData[0][2]);
      ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
      sh.getRange("D"+(row)).setValue(new Date());
    } catch(e) {
      throw 'This student allready has a sheet. Try another sheet name.';      
    }
  }
}
```

## 2, 3, 4:

see: **[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509336/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509336/how-to-copy-a-row-from-one-google-spreadsheet-to-another-google-spreadsheet-usin)**
and: **[https://productforums.google.com/gq2W7iLXnK8/](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/gq2W7iLXnK8/ge_XEtKCAwAJ)**

## 5:

maintaining formatting & design on a go (after the creation of slave sheets) from `master/instructor` sheet could lead to a lot of unwanted issues and a lot of smart scripting. its easier to set the layout at the beginning and then just replicate it on the creation

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience, and thanks for your assistance!
I copied the script from '1' above as is into the script editor and ran but nothing happened that I am aware of - receive the error message: "This student allready has a sheet. Try another sheet name. (line 25, file "Code")".
The 'master' spreadsheet has a header row with two columns, 'Name' and 'Email' and 14 rows (Name 1, Email 1; Name 2, Email 2 etc).
Am I supposed to alter any of the text of the 'function onOpen()' script you provided to match the data in the 'master' spreadsheet?

Comment: Regarding 1, I think that one of the problems with that part of the answer is that it creates sheets not spreadsheets. Another problem is that there isn't any description of what the code does and how it works, and more important how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you found ([link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#create(String,Integer,Integer))) is the reference documentation of a specific method but it's not enough.

If you are intending to use scripts you should know or be ready to learn the basics of programming and JavaScript.

One of the basics skills required is "data handling", in other words, to be able to programmatically use literals and variables to handle values and objects in JavaScript.

Regarding taking data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet the required skills are reading and writing values from/to the spreadsheet. This is explained on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Please note that the term **spreadsheet** refers to the file which is able to have one or more **sheets**.

Comment: Thank you. I will study this information. In the meantime, will you read the initial answer from User0 and my subsequent response to see if User0's method may work and why I didn't see any results?

Comment: @AwR That it's not the way that this site works. If there is a follow up question derived from an answer, it should be posted as a new question.